# How to run cucumber + springboot application using Gradle in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, gradle, cucumber

I have a demo springboot application and trying to run the cucumber test cases using gradle .. In maven Its working fine but unable to run using gradle.
Can you please help me with the way to execute the gradle file either from eclipse or from command line

Below is mt build.gradle file

```
       testImplementation 'io.cucumber:cucumber-junit:5.3.0'
    testImplementation 'io.cucumber:cucumber-core:5.3.0'
    testImplementation 'io.cucumber:cucumber-spring:5.3.0'
    testImplementation 'io.cucumber:cucumber-java:5.3.0'
    testImplementation 'javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.2.8'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5' 
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'){
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
    implementation ('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'){
    exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
    exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-log4j2'     
        
    }

test{
testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
}


sourceSets {
   main.java.srcDir "src/main/java"
   main.resources.srcDir "src/main/resources"
   test.java.srcDir "src/test/java/com/b**/f**/w**/tests"
   test.resources.srcDir "src/test/resources"
}

    configurations {
    cucumberRuntime {
        extendsFrom testImplementation
    }
}



task cucumber() {

    dependsOn assemble, compileTestJava , testClasses

    doLast {

        javaexec {

            main = "cucumber.api.cli.Main"

            classpath = configurations.cucumberRuntime + sourceSets.main.output + sourceSets.test.output

            args = ['--plugin', 'pretty', '--glue', 'com.b**.f**.w**.tests', 'src/test/resources']

        }

    }

}
}
```

And below is the error when i execute in command line using "Gradle cucumber"

```
> Task :cucumber FAILED
Feb 27, 2020 9:53:29 AM cucumber.api.cli.Main run
WARNING: You are using deprecated Main class. Please use io.cucumber.core.cli.Main
Feb 27, 2020 9:53:29 AM io.cucumber.core.cli.Main run
WARNING: By default Cucumber is running in --non-strict mode.
This default will change to --strict and --non-strict will be removed.
You can use --strict to suppress this warning
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/alekhya.machiraju/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-slf4j-impl/2.12.1/14973e22497adaf0196d481fb99c5dc2a0b58d41/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.12.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/alekhya.machiraju/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.30/c21f55139d8141d2231214fb1feaf50a1edca95e/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.30.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/alekhya.machiraju/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/1.2.3/7c4f3c474fb2c041d8028740440937705ebb473a/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Feb 27, 2020 9:53:30 AM io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime run
SEVERE: Exception while executing pickle
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
        at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:108)
        at io.cucumber.core.cli.Main.run(Main.java:75)
        at cucumber.api.cli.Main.run(Main.java:28)
        at cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(Main.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at io.cucumber.spring.SpringFactory.stop(SpringFactory.java:171)
        at io.cucumber.core.runner.Runner.disposeBackendWorlds(Runner.java:173)
        at io.cucumber.core.runner.Runner.runPickle(Runner.java:69)
        at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime.lambda$run$2(Runtime.java:100)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(Runtime.java:243)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
        at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime.lambda$run$3(Runtime.java:100)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
        at java.util.stream.SliceOps$1$1.accept(SliceOps.java:204)
        at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.tryAdvance(ArrayList.java:1359)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:486)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
        at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
        at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:101)
        ... 3 more

Feb 27, 2020 9:53:30 AM io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime run
SEVERE: Exception while executing pickle
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
        at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:108)
        at io.cucumber.core.cli.Main.run(Main.java:75)
        at cucumber.api.cli.Main.run(Main.java:28)
        at cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(Main.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at io.cucumber.spring.SpringFactory.stop(SpringFactory.java:171)
        at io.cucumber.core.runner.Runner.disposeBackendWorlds(Runner.java:173)
        at io.cucumber.core.runner.Runner.runPickle(Runner.java:69)
        at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime.lambda$run$2(Runtime.java:100)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(Runtime.java:243)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
        at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime.lambda$run$3(Runtime.java:100)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
        at java.util.stream.SliceOps$1$1.accept(SliceOps.java:204)
        at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.tryAdvance(ArrayList.java:1359)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:486)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
        at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
        at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:101)
        ... 3 more

Exception in thread "main" io.cucumber.core.exception.CompositeCucumberException: There were 2 exceptions:
  java.lang.NullPointerException(null)
  java.lang.NullPointerException(null)
        at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:120)
        at io.cucumber.core.cli.Main.run(Main.java:75)
        at cucumber.api.cli.Main.run(Main.java:28)
        at cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(Main.java:15)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\alekhya.machiraju\eclipse-workspace\bProjet name\build.gradle' line: 133

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':cucumber'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.2.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
```

My Folder stricuture is as below

```
src/test/java

 ---- com.b**.f**.w**.tests
----------------Cucumberrunnertest.java
----------------Stepdefinition.java
src/test/reaources
----------------cucumber.feature
```

Comment: Can you try cucumber version v5.4.21?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem as you, but Gradle wouldn't run my Junit 5 + Cucumber tests. It seams like Cucumber doesn't have any Junit 5 support, so I had to revert back to Junit 4 (also known as Junit 5 vintage).

My trick was to enable legacy Junit-support in my `build.gradle`.

```
test {
  // Use old (Junit 4) runner since Cucumber doesn't support Junit 5 *sigh*
  useJUnit()
  // useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

The reset of my code/setup:

build.gradle

```
plugins {
  id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.1.RELEASE'
  id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.8.RELEASE'
  id 'java'
}

group = 'se.snorbu.cucumber'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
configurations {
  compileOnly {
    extendsFrom annotationProcessor
  }
}

repositories {
  // Use jcenter for resolving dependencies.
  // You can declare any Maven/Ivy/file repository here.
  jcenter()
}

dependencies {
  // Spring
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'

  // Cucumber
  testCompile 'io.cucumber:cucumber-java:6.6.0'
  testCompile 'io.cucumber:cucumber-junit:6.6.0'
  testCompile 'io.cucumber:cucumber-spring:6.6.0'
  testCompile 'io.cucumber:cucumber-junit-platform-engine:6.6.0'

  // Misc
  testCompileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
  testAnnotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'

  // Junit5
  testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
    exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
  }
}

test {
  // Use old (Junit 4) runner since Cucumber doesn't support Junit 5 *sigh*
  useJUnit()
}
```

The Cucumber-runner/-context

```
package com.example.webapp;

import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import io.cucumber.spring.CucumberContextConfiguration;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

@CucumberContextConfiguration
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        plugin = {"pretty", "junit:build/cucumber-junit.xml", "html:build/cucumber.html"},
        features = "classpath:/"
)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class ContextConfiguration {

}
```

My stepdef

```
package com.example.webapp.steps;

import io.cucumber.java.en.Given;
import io.cucumber.java.en.Then;
import io.cucumber.java.en.When;
import io.cucumber.junit.platform.engine.Cucumber;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import se.snorbu.cucumber.webapp.PizzaClient;

import static org.hamcrest.core.Is.is;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultHandlers.print;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

@Slf4j
@Cucumber
public class OrderPizzaSteps {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    private ResultActions mvcResult;

    @Given("A pizza")
    public void givenAPizza() {
       // Do setup
    }

    @When("I order a pizza")
    public void whenOrderAPizza() throws Exception {
       // Do something
       
       mvcResult = mockMvc.perform(
                post("/order")
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .content("{\"pizza\": \"pepperoni\"}")
        );
    }

    @Then("I should receive an order-id")
    public void thenShouldReceiveOrderid() throws Exception {
       // Do assertion

       mvcResult
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("id", is("A12")));
    }
}
```